# TYPO3 Fluid: Don't send all the inputs of a form

Tags: jquery, forms, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a Fluid View with some `<f:form.hidden/>` fields.

Most of them are populated by jQuery magic (like Autocomplete; Checkboxes are added together, then put into a hidden field, ..), therefor I added some plain html, non fluid inputs, which I won't need in the action, which are just for the user.

So, is it possible to just send the fluid viewhelper generated inputs and remove the non-fluid plain inputs from the request arguments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `name` attribute from these custom inputs you don't want to send. It will prevent joining them into the request.

Use `id` attribute in custom inputs to find required elements instead.